# iOS Performance, Labels/Textfields vs PNGs

Tags: ios, performance, text

Just working on an iPad app with a significant amount of text and I was wondering if use UITextFields and UILabels was more of a performance/memory hit than simply using a UIImageView with a PNG of the text.

In some cases the text animates, but it most cases its static.

Thank you.

Update:
Taking Marc's advice I did a little digging with a new XCode project. Here are the experiement details:

Test 1:

- Brand new Single View Template XCode Project for iPad (not using storyboards)
- One Image view centered with a 678x828 image of the paragraph text (36k image)

  - The custom fonts and stylings were baked into the image.

The result:
**756kb of Live Bytes** & **842kb of Live Bytes w/ Retina PNG**

Test 2:

- added a second Image View with a different paragraph (699x749 82k)

The result:
**767kb of Live Bytes** & **854kb of Live Bytes w/ Retina PNG**

Test 3:

- Took the same copy and added 4 UILabels
- Styled the fonts to match the fonts of the baked in PNG
- Embedded custom fonts

The result:
**965kb of Live Bytes**

Test 4:

- added 4 more custom text labels with the same text & style from the second image view

The result:
**1024kb of Live Bytes**

From this angle it appears that using PNGs with baked in copy and styling has a lower memory foot print and scales better. Obviously this is a very quick & dirty experiment.

Comment: why don't you benchmark it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate? [Is there any performance or memory overhead using UIImage or UILabel or NSString in Quartz2D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477734/is-there-any-performance-or-memory-overhead-using-uiimage-or-uilabel-or-nsstring)

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'll have a look into it with instruments. I thought I would ask the community if someone had already spent the effort looking into it and had a definitive answer. If not, I'll post back my results here.

Comment: Question then, would the only reason why you would want to use UILabel (since you're not changing it) be if the screen resolution ever increased or if you wanted to port over to iPhone or target non-retina displays without having to do extra work? Or would UIImage scale the exact same?

Comment: The main reason I would want to use a UILabel is that it more flexible from a maintenance stand point. It's easier to edit the label then making 2 new PNGs (standard and retina). I did the above using standard res PNGs, I'll update the tests with retina PNGs.